# Lambda Nodejs Get request error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, lambda

I've got the following lambda function. I'm trying to make a GET request and return the data. I'm getting the error "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Does anyone know why I might be getting this?

```
'use strict';
var http = require('https');

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        host: 'www.somehost.com',
        path: '/somepath',
        headers: {
          'Authorization':'Bearer someBearerToken'
        },
        method: 'GET'
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log("success! data is: ", res)
      resolve(res);
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    }); 

    // send the request
    req.write('');
    req.end();
});
```

Comment: It is most likely due to you trying to `console.log` the response object directly instead of a subset of its values, like the body. Most response objects will contain circular data structures and associated functions that shouldn't be logged.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

`console.log("success! data is: ", res)`

`res` is a javascript object with reference to its own. Print the specific data you wish to inspect like

`console.log("success! data is: ", res.data)`

Comment: You saved me lots of debugging... I can't believe I missed this. Thank you.